# Display Logged In Username on master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have MRS.master with the following:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MRS.master.cs" Inherits="MRS" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div id="top2" class="top2">
            <a href="Page1.aspx" class="mainlist">Page1</a>
            <a href="Page2.aspx" class="mainlist" ></a>
        </div>
        <div id="top3" class="top3">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager> 
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Register" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="Register_Click"/>
                <asp:Label ID="uname" Text="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="Pwd" Text="Password" CssClass="label" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" textmode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Login" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="Login_Click" />
                  &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label3" Text="" runat="server" CssClass="label"/>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="User" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
      </div>
<div id="down" class="down" style="color:wheat">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

          </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>                             
        </div>

</form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And MRS.master.cs:

```
string username = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          Label4.Text = (string)(Session["New"]);;
        }
    protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=004-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MRS;User Id=sa;Password=***");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from LoginDetails where Uname='" + UserName.Text + "'", con);
            int cnt = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            con.Close();
            if (cnt == 0) {
                Label3.Text = "User does not exist.";
            }
            else
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select Password from LoginDetails where Uname='" + UserName.Text + "'", con);
                string pwd = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                con.Close();
                if (pwd == password.Text)
                {
                    username = UserName.Text;             
                    Session["New"] = username;
                    Label4.Text = UserName.Text;                   
                }
                else{Label3.Text = "Login details are wrong";}
            }
        }
```

I have two pages, Page1.aspx, Page2.aspx and I added the following to each:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MRS.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Page1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page1" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I added the same code to Page2.aspx also.
Page1 is starting page.After successful login 'Label4' is displaying Username, If I navigate to Page2 'Label4' is not displaying anything and if I come back to Page1 then 'Label4' is showing nothing.

How can I display Username on all pages. I already used Session.

Comment: Please check the events in Page2, is evident that in that page (or in any other one ) you have some logic that is overriding the Session["New"] value. Remenber that the Session values are shared by all the application pagesand changes in one place affect all the pages/code that use it. Please doble check it.

Comment: Elio.Batista, I don't have any other Events for Page2.

Comment: Ok, but in some place of your pages requests you are setting that Session value to null, please do a text search with project scope and look for Session["New"] occurences. BTW, for that purpose i prefer to use literal control (asp:Literal), it keeps values accross postbacks and it does not render html tags just text.

Comment: I figured out this, on back to Page1 from Page I am seeing the old master page there. Which is not the one that I see on first time load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in `MRS.maste.ascx.cs`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    if (Session["New"] != null)
       Label4.Text = Session["New"].ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: If I navigate to Page2 and come back to Start Page(Page1), then the label is empty.  Page2 is displaying the UserName.

Comment: @EHVR did you debugged your code. I mean is your debugger entering in this condition `if (pwd == password.Text)
                {` ???

Comment: Yes it does, for the first time I see the Username on Page1 also, If I go to Page2 and come back to Page1 then it is not displaying.

Comment: @EHVR please search for Session["New"] in your Entire Document you are setting Session["New"] to Null some where in your code.

Comment: I figured out this, on back to Page1 from Page I am seeing the old master page there. Which is not the one that I see on first time load.

Comment: on back button click, Page1 it is not displaying the name.

Comment: @EHVR I have suggested you to done this in your master page `if(!Page.IsPostBack)
  { if (Session["New"] != null)` It must not create a problem if you are not setting `Session["New"]` to Null at some other place.

Comment: It is working if I navigate between pages by clicking the links, it is not working when I click 'Back'/'Next' arrows of browser to navigate.

Comment: @EHVR are you using `SessionTimeOut` in `web.config` ?

Comment: No, I am not.Login on Page1, goto Page2 and come back to page 1 using links, I can see the name. Login on Page1, goto Page2 using link works, then If I click on Back Page1 is not showing name this time. It looks it is asking to login again.

Comment: @EHVR If you can follow my suggestion than, use labels separately for individual pages not in Master page and than at every page load try to set label with the session.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the session variable directly in the `Label.Text`?

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%= Session["New"] %>' CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: I don't see the Buttons and fields after doing the above. Just showing <%= Session["New"] %> in that division.

Comment: Did you only replace the label? It sounds weird to me that all your layout will get lost by changing this single line.

Comment: Sorry Patric, it was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

replace your `Page_Load` event in MRS.master.cs to

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(!Page.IsPostBack)
       {
          Label4.Text = (string)(Session["New"]);;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewState for labels controls is not enabled by default, so on page load of your master page you have to assign his value every time you do a postback

```
if ( null != Session["New"] )
  Label4.Text = Session["New"] .ToString();
```

Comment: should not it be like `if ( Session["New"] != null)` ?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad,  that is a matter of personal taste ;)